# compare 2 columns in dataframe and save conditions in another column in same dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to compare each value in "Inforce Counts" and "vlookup".

- If "vlookup" is "N/A" then "comparision" should be "N/A"
- If counts match  then "comparision" should be "True"
- If counts not match then "comparision" should be "False"

df1:
[image]

expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to use **pandas libraries** there a good way too.

The simplest way and more efficient (fastest) is using the function `df.apply` of the data frame. First define the function of how you calculate the new column, and then apply it with the apply function:

```
def creating_new_column(row):
    #Create your conditions
    if row["vlookup"]=="N/A":
         return ("N/A")
    
    elif row["vlookup"]==row["Inforce Counts"]:
         return(True)

    else:
         return(False)
```

An then use `apply`:

```
df["comparision"]=df.apply(lambda row: creating_new_column (row), axis=1)
```

Comment: Working for me. Thanks

Comment: What if I have to do similar comparison on multiple columns and need multiple new columns. For example, comparison of X1, X2 I need to store in X_Comp and comparison of Y1, Y2 I need to store in Y_Comp. So basically we need to have multiple comparison columns.